# Fast way to query listobject vba

Tags: excel, vba

I use excel 2016 and need to get a value from list object. There are several columns. For example three, and I need to get the value in column1 where column2=smth, column3=smth. How can I do this fast?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand the question. Do you mean like this? `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects.Item(1).Value` Where 1 is the object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobjects-item-property-excel

Comment: @HackSlash No. I don't want to find a ListObject. I want to do something like sql `select where` query with multiple conditions inside the values of a particular ListObject

Comment: How fast is fast enough?  Did you try something and that was too slow?

Comment: @Tim Williams I have tried using power query, match/index and pivot tables. I have a rather big table to look up, and (in my version) those methods worked visible slowly, or there were needed to do many manipulations on worksheet before I had values in vba variables

Comment: Match should be pretty fast - alternatives might depend on the size of the table and how many lookups you need to do.

Comment: Can you filter your column? If that filter is slow can you turn off automatic calculation?

Comment: If you want SQL syntax and speed in VBA then you need to use the ADO DB connector. In my experience it was 4x faster than using native Excel functions to find the data. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx

Comment: @Brad To filter columns in my case is not a good solution. I would like to do all in vba, without visual changes. And the sheet is protected, so I need protect/unprotect it to apply filters

Comment: @HackSlash You don't have issues with the memory leak? https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/run-time-error-2147024882-8007000e-out-of-memory-while-building-ado-recordset.313008/ ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714282/excel-access-db-ado-memory-leak-system-resource-exceeded ; https://www.msofficeforums.com/excel-programming/21433-slow-comparison-replace-script.html ; https://www.decisionmodels.com/memlimitsd.htm

Comment: @johnywhy No. I've used this technique to process quite large datasets. If you use `With` statements to manage disposal of objects and properly close your connections then ADO seems to clean up just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want SQL syntax and speed in VBA then you need to use the ADO DB connector. In my experience it was 4x faster than using native Excel functions to find the data.

It's a lengthy topic that requires you read multiple articles. Much more information than should fit in to one SO post.

Here is an example article:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx

Here is the code from that example:

```
    Const adOpenStatic = 3
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adCmdText = &H1
    
    Dim objConnection As Object
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Scripts\Test.xls;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
    
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        .Open "Select * FROM [Sheet1$] Where Number = 2", _
        objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    
        Do Until .EOF
            Debug.Print .Fields.Item("Name"), .Fields.Item("Number")
                
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    
        .Close
    End With
    
    objConnection.Close
```

Comment: But you're not querying a ListObject. You're querying the worksheet. Something like this could select from a ListObject: `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:A3]` or maybe even `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$Table1]` (i haven't tested)

Comment: It's said that ADO against an open workbook is a memory leak. https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/run-time-error-2147024882-8007000e-out-of-memory-while-building-ado-recordset.313008/ ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714282/excel-access-db-ado-memory-leak-system-resource-exceeded ; https://www.msofficeforums.com/excel-programming/21433-slow-comparison-replace-script.html ; https://www.decisionmodels.com/memlimitsd.htm

Comment: I've never had an OOM problem using this method but I'm using 64-bit office so YMMV. You will have to work within the limitations of your hardware\software combination.

Comment: the links i shared aren't the right one. Here's the original MS article about the leak (no longer available on MS website). https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/319998 - This person couldn't replicate the issue in 2014 - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c1dadb6e-ea00-4436-9a8c-9aa72623505a/bug-memory-leak-occurs-when-you-query-an-open-excel-worksheet-by-using-activex-data-objects-ado - This person experience the issue in 2016 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714282/excel-access-db-ado-memory-leak-system-resource-exceeded

Comment: @johnywhy, ok that KB says it happens when you query an OPEN excel file. The whole point of this technique is to avoid opening the file in Excel. So I would never do that. You should only be opening the file through ADO, not through Excel itself.

Comment: "You should only be opening the file through ADO, not through Excel itself." - Why? It seems perfectly reasonable for VBA to query its OWN sheets! :)

Comment: I will have to counter your why with my own. If the sheet is already open, just grab the data using Excel native functions. Why would you use ADO? I say again: The only reason I use ADO is to read from a large number of workbooks. It's orders of magnitude faster than opening them in Excel. If the sheet is already open then you lose that speed benefit.

Comment: NOTE: ADO is for querying a database. Excel is not a database. It's cool that they made a driver that can open Excel documents because you can do that from anywhere, like Access or your own application. You don't even need Excel installed to do so. Using ADO from Excel to open Excel files is quite an edge case. You can only really open a file with one process at a time. If you open in Excel and ADO at the same time then I would expect to run in to problems. Just like if you open a file from any other two processes.

Comment: "If you open in Excel and ADO at the same time then I would expect to run in to problems." - Your implication is that ADO is "opening" the file that's already open, rather than just connecting to the open instance. I'm not sure that's true. As a test, i created and queried an ADO connection to a ListObject in a workbook that had never been saved. It worked.

Comment: i contacted the 2016 guy that i mentioned. He confirmed he experienced the memory issues on Excel 2010, which is a few versions out of date.

Comment: "Excel is not a database." - Excel might not be a database, but it does contain TABLES (they are called "Tables" in Excel). Excel supports a million rows and sixteen thousand columns. Rows and columns, AKA "a data table".  "If the sheet is already open, just grab the data using Excel native functions." -- The problem is, there aren't any native functions for querying worksheet data, particularly with multi-field criteria.

Comment: There is. It's called [Power Query](https://powerquery.microsoft.com/en-us/) Or any other of the millions of ways to work with data in Excel.

Comment: "The Power Query user experience is provided through the Power Query Editor user interface. The goal of this interface is to help you apply the transformations you need simply by interacting with a user-friendly set of ribbons, menus, buttons, and other interactive components." -- Too top-heavy for my use-case. PQ is a large, feature-rich tool, with emphasis on front-end display and large datasets. I only need to pull a scalar into VBA from a sheet table, based on multi-field criteria. Not doing any front-end display. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-what-is-power-query